# Как определить является ли файл текстовым?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Как определить является ли файл текстовым при использовании python?

Comment: Для этого, вам надо уточнить, а что такое "текстовый файл" в принципе. Возможно, у вашего случая, есть более правильное решение.

Comment: С кодировкой latin-1 абсолютно любой файл можно прочитать как текстовый :) Поэтому да, нужны уточнения

Comment: Под текстовым файлом понимается лог любого сервера

Comment: Мог ли бы Вы привести пример файла?

Comment: прочитать файл в str. если ошибок нет, условно считать текстовым )

Comment: Лог, например, apache2 _PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '&' in /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini on line 107_

Comment: Лог ***любого*** сервера? Продолжайте уточнять вопрос, может быть через 3-4 итерации, он станет достаточно адекватным.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [How can I detect if a file is binary (non-text) in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/898669/4279)